# Is it possible to create a jump List for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: jumplist, microsoft-edge

Edge will not accept dragged and dropped shortcuts like other programs. I cannot find any local file nor registry entry that could store an entry for Edge jump list items.

Answer (score 0):

The following Powershell script will open a web page, e.g., nytimes.com, in your default browser:
[Line 1] cd ..
[Line 2] cd ..
[Line 3] cd \windows
[Line 4] .\explorer.exe http://www.nytimes.com

So, (1.) Pin Powershell to the Taskbar. (2.) Write a script for each page you want on the jumplist, (3.) Create a shortcut pointing to each script, (4.) drag the shortcuts to Powershell. You can now use Powershell as a proxy for Edge on the Taskbar